# GET возвращает пустую страницу или страницу загрузки

Tags: python, requests

Совсем недавно начал учить Python, попробовал создать простой GET запрос через библиотеку requests:

```
response = requests.get('https://www.twitch.tv')
with open('test.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```

Открываю test.html:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это экран загрузки сайта https://www.twitch.tv, а я хотел получить конечную версию уже после загрузки. Подскажите, как можно обойти эту загрузку или что почитать по этой теме.

Comment: Конечную версию можно получить только используя браузер

Comment: Используйте `selenium`

Comment: @Viewed большое спасибо, буду учить